# The Area of Trapezium is given by $A=\frac{1}{2}(4-x^2)(2x+4)$

Tags: calculus, area

The Area of Trapezium is given by: $$A=\frac{1}{2}(4-x^2)(2x+4)$$ Find the Maximum area of Trapezium.

Hi, can anyone help me with this question. I know we differentiate the equation, but i don't know what to do next. Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum of the curve (in this case of the area of the trapezium) can be found through the zeroes of the derivative
$$A'=-x(2x+4)+(4-x^2)=0.$$
This equation will lead to two solutions $x_1,x_2$ (potential maximums or minimums). What you have to do next is to demonstrate which one is a maximum. You can do it by analyzing the second derivative, $A''$ in the pints found before, $x_1,x_2$. If $A''(x_1)<0$ then $x_1$ is a maximum. In the opposite case, $A''(x_1)>0$ $x_1$ is a minimum (and same for $x_2$). I hope it is clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$A(x)=\frac{1}{2}(4-x^2)(2x+4)$$ 
gives
$$A'(x)=-(3x-2)(x+2)$$ If there exists a maximum of $A$, it has to be found among the values $A(x_0)$ for which $A'(x_0)=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks. I got x=-2, 2/3. so 2/3 must be the maximum right.

Comment: @Rahul How do you know it must be 2/3, but not -2?

Answer (score -1):

$$A'=-3x^2-4x+4=0$$
$$(x+2)(3x-2)=0$$
$$x=-2, \frac{2}{3}$$
$$x=\frac{2}{3}$$

since -2 cannot be a maximum